# Recursive function count In laravel

Tags: php, laravel, count, model, recursive-query

Please help me out with the Recursive function in the model, I want a count on multilevel subcategories.

```
$userChild = Referral::with(['get_children'])->where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count using **withCount**
Check the below URL for the more detail:

[More detail here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-eloquent-withsum-and-withcount-exampleexample.html)

Comment: again that's for individual one I need for all the subcategories like a laptop has a count of 2 and  mobile has 3 I need a total answer as 5

Answer (score 0):

In magento e-commerce the category path add two columns to resolve easily this problem. If you can change it, will help you in the future. Magento category table is like this.

| id | path | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1/2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1/3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1/2/1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2/1 | 2 |

With this structure, you can use like to find all level "select * from table where path like "1/%"

Comment: You can add another column with parent id reference.